# How to change Bootstrap elements' properties in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'd like to update the progress bar property **aria-valuenow** of the Bootstrap's progress bar using data binding in Angular but i'm having a hard time figuring out which commands to use

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-sm-6" *ngFor="let corso of corsi">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top w-100 d-block" src="../assets/img/pexels-pixabay-247791.jpg">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                    <h3>{{corso.titolo}}</h3>
                </div>

                <p class="card-text pb-2 fw-bold">Avanzamento corso: {{corso.progresso}}%</p>

                <div class="progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;"></div>
                </div>   
             
                <p class="card-text pt-3">Data scadenza: {{corso.scadenza}}</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary d-flex align-items-center" type="button">Vedi corso</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to get the attribute from the DOM using `element.getElementsByClassName`, since I'm iterating on a mock-array, but I can't figure out how to access the HTMLCollection array

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CORSI } from '../../mock-corsi'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-card',
    templateUrl: './card.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
})

export class CardComponent implements OnInit {
    corsi = CORSI;

    constructor() { 
        console.log("Constructor partito")
    
        var bar = document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar');
        console.log(bar);
    }
    ngOnInit(): void { }
}
```

[HTMLCollection array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifeZz.jpg)

It's a very simple application but I'd like to understand how to access data like that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is make the `aria-valuenow` attribute dynamic, you can do so using this syntax.

```
[attr.aria-valuenow]="valueNow"
```

where `valueNow` will be defined in your `.ts` file.

Your HTML will now look like:

```
<div class="progress-bar" [attr.aria-valuenow]="valueNow" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;"></div>
```

and in your `.ts` file you can have

`valueNow : number =  80;`

Comment: the SO wants to know what the `valueNow` that set by default onInit (80 can be 100 etc.)

Comment: Kind of, I'd like to make it dynamic like other pieces of {{code}} in the HTML, getting data from the array "corsi" in the .ts and putting it into the progress-bar div element. Your solution doesn't work atm.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem in stackblitz?

Comment: I'm new to stackblitz so later I'll take a look, anyway the problem is only about the component you see in my post. Is there something specific you want to see to understand more? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use `[attr.somthing]` to set attr with binding .
to set current value use reference `#` with `getAttribute`

**In HTML**

```
<div #ref [attr.aria-valuenow]="setAttr(ref)"></div>
```

**In TS**

```
setAttr(ref){
   return ref.getAttribute('aria-valuenow') + 20;
}
```